# Remove line breaks from csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that can contain a column with multiple lines. But, I need the data on that column to be in one singular line, otherwise it will cause me trouble when I import that data on my database.

I tried differents methods to remove carriage returns, blank space and many things but none of them really helped me.

```
$snip = str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $snip);
$snip = preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', '', $snip); 
$snip = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:]]~', '', $snip); 
$snip = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:][:space:]]~', '', $snip);
```

My CSV looks like:
[wrong code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uhI3.png)

And it need to look like:

```
Test_1;Test_2
singular line;"multiple Lines In same cell"
```

Comment: Please can you share the output of `var_dump($snip)`?  That might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: string(6) "Test_1" string(12) "singularline" string(5) "Lines" string(11) "Insamecell""

Comment: _"otherwise it will cause me trouble when I import that data on my database"_ - and how exactly are you doing that, this import? Sounds like your problem might actually lie on that end - you are probably not _reading_ the data using the correct method?

Comment: Actually I started from the beginning again, on my first try I was using feof method to read the file, and that is what was causing me trouble!
And changed it to fgetcsv and it worked perfectly. No matter what I tried would always end on a cell with 3 different lines, because the method I used to read the file was wrong. 
Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegExp, it will replace all carriage returns or line feeds with a single space:

```
$snip = preg_replace('/[\r\n]++/', ' ', $snip);
```